# How to find equilibrium points of a nonlinear second order ode?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I have an ode of the following form $$y''+by'=a+f(y)$$ where $$a=mg\sin(\theta),\quad f(y)=k y\left(\frac{L-\sqrt{y^2+h^2}}{\sqrt{y^2+h^2}}\right)$$ are constants. How do I find the equilibrium points for this equation?

For an equilibrium solution, I tried to put $y'=0\implies y''=0.$ Hence $$\sin(\theta)=\frac{ky(\sqrt{y^2+h^2}-L)}{mg\sqrt{y^2+h^2}}.$$ What do I do after this?

Comment: You will have to square the expression twice in order to obtain a polynomial. Then you will have to solve the polynomial. You can use wolfram alpha to solve the equation for y.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible answer:** Put $y'=z$ then the above ODE reduce to following system of equations:
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{cases}
z'=a-bz+f(y)\\
y'=z.
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
Then the equlibrium solution is: Solution of the system $z'=0$ and $y'=0$ simultaneously.

Comment: You answer is the same procedure as proposed by the op but formulated for a system.